# Checkbox getting toggled on ctrl+spacebar

Tags: checkbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I've started working on an application which is being developed in ASP.Net MVC2 for Azure.

The checkboxes present in the form are not toggling state on spacebar as they are supposed to but on ctrl+spacebar (in internet explorer). When i use internet explorer for doing the same operation on some form on the internet spacebar works fine.

Why is my app behaving differently then. I am including jQuery classes for some UI effects too.

Thanks,

Abhishek